# Interfaces, static classes problem

Tags: java

I am currently moving all my Game code to another package so that I can simply reuse it when I create another similar game.

I am having some problems with this though.

```
public interface Sprite {
...
}

abstract class AbstractSprite implements Sprite {
...
}

public interface Builder<T> {
    public T build();
}

class GameObjectImpl extends AbstractSprite {
    public static class GameObjectBuilder implements Builder<GameObjectImpl> {
    ...
    }
}
```

I am using a Builder Pattern to create my GameObjectImpl objects.  However, the client (the person using my game engine) will only have access to the Sprite interface.

How can I get the client to create GameObjectImpl using builder and only having access to the Sprite Interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add one more publicly visible class in the same package called Builders:

```
public final class Builders {

    public static Builder<? extends Sprite> newGameObjectBuilder() {
        return new GameObjectImpl.GameObjectBuilder();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does Builder need to be an interface? Why not just make a builder-like factory? It seems like you want to tie the interface to this particular implementation.

```
public final class SpriteBuilder {
  private final Foo foo;
  private int property = 0;

  public SpriteBuilder(Foo importantMandatoryValue) {
    this.foo = importantMandatoryValue;
  }

  public SpriteBuilder setProperty(int theProperty) {
    this.property = property;
    return this;
  }

  public Sprite build() {
    return new GameObjectImpl(foo, property);
  }
}
```

You might call `SpriteBuilder` a `GameObjectImplFactory`... and make a similar class for each one of your `Sprite` implementations. You just have to make sure they will only return the `Sprite` type.

In your example, you would actually say something like `public class GameObjectImplFactory implements Builder<Sprite>`.

Hope this helps and makes sense :-).

Comment: The clients will be building their own Sprites so I will not give them any pre-configured sprites

Comment: Where is there a pre-configured sprite in my example? You said the client needs to use a builder right? My point is that you provide them a builder that only returns a Sprite (meaning they have to adhere to the Sprite interface... and you can make your implementation package-private). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to make the `Builder` class generic... instead `Builder.build()` should be returning a Sprite object.  Right now the `build()` method is returning `T` which in your case is a `GameObjectImpl`