# Exposing a Builder Class to client code

Tags: java

I am moving my Game to its own package to make it useful in future games.
I Implemented a Builders class as suggested by one of the user here: [Interfaces, static classes problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376660/interfaces-static-classes-problem)

```
public final class Builders {
    public static Builder<? extends Sprite> newGameObjectBuilder(Point location, int drawable) {
        return new GameObjectImpl.GameObjectBuilder(location, drawable);
    }
}
```

The problem now is that the client code cannot use the builder methods (Example below).  I get the following:

```
"The method onReceiveKey(new Sprite.ReceiveKeys(){}) is undefined for the type Builder<capture#4-of ? extends Sprite>"
```

Basically I cannot use any of the methods inside the public static call GameObjectBuilder.

`onReceiveKey` is not working.  Only the `build()` method of the `Builder` interface is available.

```
public static Sprite newSoldier(int x, int y) {
    return  Builders.newGameObjectBuilder(new Point(x,y), R.drawable.soldier)
    .onReceiveKey(new Sprite.ReceiveKeys() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(int keyCode, Sprite self, Room room ) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, Sprite self, Room room ) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                self.moveY(room, 1, Direction.S); 
            }
            else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP){
                self.moveY(room, -1, Direction.N); 
            }
            else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT){
                self.moveX(room, -1,Direction.W); 
            }
            else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT){
                self.moveX(room, 1, Direction.E);
            }
        }
    })
    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is your builder is like this

```
public interface Builder<T> {
    public T build();
}
```

Just do

```
public interface SpriteBuilder<T extends Sprite> extends Builder<T> {
    Builder<T> onReceiveKey(Sprite.ReceiveKeys receiver);
}
```

and change Builders to

```
public final class Builders {
    public static SpriteBuilder newGameObjectBuilder(Point location, int drawable) {
        return new GameObjectImpl.GameObjectBuilder(location, drawable);
    }
}
```

and your `GameObjectBuilder` to

```
class GameObjectImpl extends AbstractSprite {
    public static class GameObjectBuilder implements SpriteBuilder {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do Builder<T extends Sprite> I get a syntax error.  I have put this interface inside my Sprite interface

Comment: I got this working but I had to declare like this SpriteBuilder<T extends Sprite> extends Builder<T>